# How to include orm mapping file/resource in spring application context which is externalized

Tags: spring

Our requirement is to override the Entity schema at run time using some configuration. In our application we have different schema for different entities in a single persistence Unit and we need to override those schema at run time.

The approach I have checked mostly is using orm.xml file and define the schema which we need at the deployment site.

We are using Spring + JPA + Hibernate , and we are not using persistence.xml as everything is defined in spring application context.xml.

With this requirement , We want to externalize the orm.xml files and include in the spring application context.

so my question is:

How to externalize the ORM.xml file and include in the spring application context.

Comment: I am able to achieve what I wanted using hard coded file path:

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works with jvm argument:

file:#{systemProperties.BFconfigLocation}conf/persistence/BFBANKFUSION.xml

where BFconfigLocation is set as JVM argument.